# Event handling function

Tags: javascript, event-handling

In the task, you need to change the background colour of the block to green when you press the G key, but no changes are made.

```
<body>
<div id="colorOutput">
</div>

<script>
   let div = document.querySelector("#colorOutput");
   document.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
        if (event.code == "Enter") changeToGreen();
    })
   function changeToGreen() {
       div.style.backgroundСolor = "green";
   }
</script>
```

Comment: `backgroundСolor` <-- That `С` is not a `C` Run this in the console `console.log(escape("С"), escape("C"))`

Comment: your div is empty, so this element cannot process any keyboard event

Comment: and in addition to both of those points, the `code` property is not going to be equal to `"Enter"` if the user presses a G!

Comment: @epascarello oh wow!! How on earth did you spot that??

Comment: @JeremyThille Went to edit the question and saw the funky C in the editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below JS code.

```sh
const div = document.getElementById("colorOutput");
window.addEventListener("keydown", (e)=>{
    e.code === "Enter" ? changeToGreen() : null;
});
function changeToGreen() {
       alert("JAI HARI");
       div.style.backgroundСolor = "green";
   }
```

Use `window` instead of `document` for Event Listener.